# Amplify Angular 7 build error - 'NgModule' calls 'ɵmakeDecorator'

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, angular7, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify package in my Angular 7 App. It works fine with ng serve. But It's giving below error when try to prod build using ng build -- prod

```
ERROR in aws-amplify-angular\dist\src\aws-amplify-angular.module.ts(82,2): Error during template compile of 'AmplifyAngularModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called in 'NgModule'
    'NgModule' calls 'ɵmakeDecorator'.
```

Everything looks fine in my code, not sure about this error. I researched in google but I couldn't find much. Let me know if anyone has come across this issue and knows the fix.

Comment: did you try ng build --prod --aot=false

Comment: yep. that also doesn't work